# Python logs between multiple modules only work in functions called by original file?

Tags: python, logging, module

I'm trying to add logging between a couple different modules. Why, when I place a log somewhere that isn't referenced in my original file, why does all logging break? I'm importing `logging` in both files. I import the `other_file` in `file1`.

Here is an example of what I'm running into with comments in `other_file`:

## file1

```
import other_file

def main():
    logging.debug("Start")
    other_file.use_bar()
    logging.debug("End")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import logging
    logging.basicConfig(filename='logfile.log',
                    level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
    main()
```

## other_file

```
import logging

def get_something():
    something = 'foo'
    # PUTTING A LOG HERE BREAKS ALL LOGS
    return something

bar = get_something()
# SO DOES PUTTING A LOG HERE

def use_bar():
    print(bar)
    logging.info("log bar")  # THIS LOG WORKS FINE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is related to how module import works in python.

Well, when importing the module other_file, Python automatically evaluates the line `bar = set_something()` by executing the function and store the result in `bar` and all of this is done before the logging starts. About putting a log in the line after `bar = get_something()` won't work because it'll be executed before the logging begins.

(I imagine that you'll need to use the value of `bar` to be global, if not, you can declare it inside the function `use_bar()` and in this case, the problem is solved.)

So the solution here might be replacing the line `bar = get_something()` by `bar = get_something` and now, `bar` is no longer a variable instead, Python will consider it as a function which is `get_something` and you can use it like : `bar()`.

So if you want to preserve the same structure of your code, you have to change the `other_file` code as below :

## other_file

```
import logging

def get_something():
    something = 'foo'
    # PUTTING A LOG HERE BREAKS ALL LOGS
    return something

bar = get_something

def use_bar():
    print(bar())
    logging.info("log bar")
```

But I suggest that you use this code instead which is (let's say) more pythonic :

## file1

```
import logging
import other_file

def logger_config():
    logging.basicConfig(filename='logfile.log',
                        level=logging.DEBUG,
                        format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
    return logging.getLogger(__name__)

def main():
    # Get the logger
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.debug("Start")
    other_file.use_bar()
    logger.debug("End")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

## other_file

```
import logging

# Get the logger from the main module (file1)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def get_something():
    something = 'foo'
    # Your log here
    logger.info('Test log')
    return something

bar = get_something

def use_bar():
    print(bar())
    logger.info("log bar")
```

Answer (score 1):

#### What's the problem?

The function `get_something` is called before logging be configured. Then, it don't will appear on your `logfile`.
This occur when you import the module `other_file`. Python automatically execute the function `get_something` and assign the result to variable `bar`. **Take care on it**.

```
bar = get_something()
# SO DOES PUTTING A LOG HERE
```

#### Suggested solution

To solve this problem, just assign the function `get_something` to bar, without call. Then, call `bar()` on function `use_bar`.

```
bar = get_something
# SO DOES PUTTING A LOG HERE

def use_bar():
    print(bar())
    logging.info("log bar")  # THIS LOG WORKS FINE
```

#### Complete Solution

**main.py**

```
import other_file
import logging  # Is recommend import modules on the top

def main():
    logging.debug("Start")
    other_file.use_bar()
    logging.debug("End")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(filename='logfile.log',
                    level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
    main()
```

**other_file.py**

```
import logging

def get_something():
    something = 'foo'
    # PUTTING A LOG HERE BREAKS ALL LOGS
    return something

bar = get_something
# SO DOES PUTTING A LOG HERE

def use_bar():
    print(bar())
    logging.info("log bar")  # THIS LOG WORKS FINE
```